# Pendulum and Loss of Energy

Tags: energy

A pendulum loses energy with each swing, so does the swing of a pendulum violate the law of conservation of energy?

Comment: I think you are a bit mixed up in what you really want to know. The movement of a  pendulum does not break the conservation of energy law. But even though it slows down, over time, and loses energy, it still keeps the clock working properly to record time accurately.  If you read this link , it might answer what I am guessing you are confused about. http://www.explainthatstuff.com/how-pendulum-clocks-work.html

Comment: You are thinking constancy of energy in the pendulum/gravity system. Conservation of energy allows a current of energy (aka, work) to change the energy in the system. Energy isn't created or destroyed, but it moves around. Energy is always conserved.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

That is so because the energy **of an isolated system** is conserved, and the pendulum is not isolated: the reason it slows down a bit at every swing is because it is losing energy to the surrounding atmosphere and at its suspension point.

Energy is being transfered or converted, not destroyed, so there's no violation of conservation of energy.